# Android Media Player - Getting the number of times a video played in SetLooping

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I am Playing the video in loop using set Looping(true) option and i will stop the media player after a particular event happened. It is working fine. But i want to know the number of times that my video got played in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaPlayer doesn't provide that information, you need to make it loop yourself and count how many times it has restarted. To do this, something in your app will need to extend OnCompletionListener and do something like

```
int count = 0;
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    count++;
    mediaplayer.seekTo(0);
    mediaplayer.start();
}
```

And you need to set `mediaPlayer.setLooping(false)`